# Quering a post object based on another related post object

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, post-meta

I have two post types - Ticket and Event

Each ticket has a meta called 'event_id' which connects it to an Event.

Suppose I want to fetch all events with more than 3 tickets. I want to do it in a single WP_Query so that the results can be paginated properly. How can I do this?